# Cannot view new records in database after binding from user's input with Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring

I am new to Stackoverflow as I am new to Web Development; I am developing a web survey using Spring MVC, Tomcat and MySQL; I have a problem when I answer question on my web survey; infact I get a Null Exception Error (as reported below), without being able to see new records in my Database.

[(In this image there are some notes about elements of my code such as the dictionary DictAnswer that I want to use to get the question of the survey and to make the user able to input answers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Dx0.jpg)

Thanks in advance to everyone that can help me. I post here below my files.

1) My classes (every class has their setters and getters):

```
public class Answer {
int id;
Question question;
int value;
Date date;
Users user;
int time; }

public class Question {
int id;
String text;
String description;
Survey survey; } 

public class DictAnswer {
private HashMap <String, ArrayList<Answer>> dizComp = new HashMap <String, 
ArrayList<Answer>> (); }
```

2) My Controller (Get and Post method):

```
@Controller
public class QuestController {
@Autowired  
QuestDao dao; 
// with dao I get record from database such as question for survey

// Get Method to give to the html a dictionary with key(title of survey)
// and value(ArrayList of Answers that have Questions as attribute) where
// for each answer we have pre-compiled question from the database and other 
// attributes such as answer have to be compiled by user's input

@ModelAttribute ("dizAnswer")
public CompilazioneQuestionario getDict() {
    DictAnswer dizRisp = new DictAnswer ();
    dizRisp.setDizComp(dao.getQuestion());
    return dizRisp;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/survey/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ModelAndView viewQuest(@PathVariable int id, ModelMap model){ 
    return new ModelAndView("survey", "dizRisposte", dizRisp);
}

// Post Method

@RequestMapping(value="/survey/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String saveRisp(@Validated @ModelAttribute("dizRisposte") 
DictAnswer rl, ModelMap model, BindingResult result){ 
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error";
    } 
    dao.saveAnswer(rl);         
    return "success"; 
}
```

3) Method DAO to save new answers:

```
public void saveAnswer(DictAnswer items) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Answer>> diz = items.getDizComp();
    for(int i = 0; i < diz.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList <Answer> value = diz.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < value.size(); j++) {
            String sql="INSERT INTO answer(value, date, time, 
            id_question, id_user)" +
            " VALUES (" + value.get(j).getValue() + ", '2018-12-11', 100, " 
            + value.get(j).getQuestion().getId() + ", 3)"; 
            template.update(sql);
        }
    }
```

4) Part of HTML:

```
<ul class="infobox">
    <li class="info" id="titolo"> Nome Programma</li>
    <li class="info" id="nome">${user.nome}</li>
    <li class="info" id="cognome">${user.cognome}</li>
    <li class="info" id="progetto">${user.progetti.nome}</li>
    <li class="info" id="ente">${user.ente.nome}</li>
</ul>
<div class="istruzioni">
    <p>Istruzioni </p>
</div>

<form:form method="post" action="/projectwork/survey/success" 
modelAttribute="dizRisposte"> 
 <div class="total">
    <c:forEach var="survey" items="${dizRisposte.dizComp}" 
    varStatus="status">
        <div class="titquest">
            <h2> ${survey.key}</h2>
        </div>
        <ol>
            <c:forEach var="answ" items="${survey.value}" 
            varStatus="status">
                <li>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="domande">
                            <h1>${answ.question.text}</h1>
                            <p>${answ.question.description}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="risposte">
                            <form:radiobutton 
                            path="${item.value}" 
                            id="ris${answ.question.id}.1" 
                            name="${answ.question.id}" value="1"/> 
                            <label for="ris${risp.domande.id}.1">1</label>
                            <form:radiobutton 
                            path="${item.valore}" 
                            id="ris${risp.domande.id}.2" 
                            name="${risp.domande.id}" value="2" />
                            <label for="ris${risp.domande.id}.2">2</label>                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ol>
 </c:forEach>
    </div>
    <div class="bottone">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="send">
    </div>

</form:form>
```

5) File Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.emit</groupId>
<artifactId>projectwork</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>projectwork</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring mvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL JDBC driver -->
    <!-- mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet Spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-milestones</id>
        <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource- 
        milestones</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>projectwork</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

6) ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.emit.projectwork.dao.QuestDao.saveRis(QuestDao.java:120)
com.emit.projectwork.controller.QuestController.saveRisp(QuestController.java:75)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?  What are you using for your front end templating (JSTL, Thymeleaf, etc...)?

Comment: I am using Spring MVC and JSTL

Comment: (Sorry if I forgot some detail but I am new to web development)

Comment: I add to my post also pom.xml if it can be useful

Comment: Is your INSERT query actually inserting the data into the database?

Comment: the problem is that the query doesn't actually insert the data in the database; now i tried to insert a @ModelAttribute method into the controller to pass the modelAttribute to get and post method of controller and I get a java.lang.NullPointerException Error

Comment: Is your template in your `DAO ` properly autowired? Also post your error.

Comment: I have just posted also my error; however in Controller I inserted @Autowired DAO, I think correctly. Could it be I have made some mistake in using the model attribute?

Comment: Solved! I found that the error was about the use of model attribute annotation in my controller and the use of path in .jsp file